# PVRTCv2 or v4 Encoding Can't be Loaded on Android - Cocos2dx

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I would like to ask a few question about texture encoding and loading pvr.ccz file in Android. I'm using Cocos2dx Game Engine.

1. I can't load pvr.ccz file with texture encoding format PVRTCv2 and PVRTCv4. But, I can load it with RGBA 8888, RGBA 4444, etc. I've checked cocos2dx source. It just doesn't allow Android to load with those two encoding format. I would like to know if there is any work-around to load for those two encoding format in Android.
2. I've changed the pvr.ccz file encoding to RGBA 8888. And it can be loaded in both iOS and Android. But, the problem is when the pvr.ccz file is larger than approximately 2.4 MB, Android can't load it again. In memory usage, it's telling me that the size of pvr.ccz file is even larger than 16 MB. Maybe it's because Android decompress pvr.ccz file. I would like to know if there any work-around for that memory issue in Android.

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab P7500 to test and I assume it use PowerVR GPU. It should be ok with PVRTCv2 or PVRTCv4. But, in the source of cocos2dx, it's not checking anything related to GPU. It just don't allow Android to load PVRTCv2 or PVRTCv4. Our Game is using too many Graphic, if we are using RGBA 8888, the size of the game would become around 40 MB while the size would be only 18 MB when we use PVRTCv2.

Any Suggestion would be Appreciate !! .. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a fork of cocos2d and tuning it for your needs?

If you are targeting more Android devices I would go for **ETC1** compression for opaque textures first, gives decent compression and would make your apk smaller. Check [android.opengl.ETC1Util](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/ETC1Util.html) namespace for some utility code to load just one compressed image (you will need to load each mipmap level from a compressed file).

For non-opaque textures use **vendor specific extensions**. Check this: [Android OpenGL Texture Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148795/android-opengl-texture-compression)