# what is the best way for loading assets (images) into memory using opengl?

Tags: c, performance, memory, opengl-es

This question is not regarding a specific platform and is related to OpenGL ES.

My brother and I are creating a simple 2d adventure game but we are both new to pure OpenGL programming and are probably missing something obvious.

We are loading a simple PNG texture that will be the game background. That texture is a full HD (1920x1080) png file has a size on the disk of 2.7MB. Once loaded in memory that same file now holds nearly 9MB in memory.

Here is a sample of the code in charge of loading a file.

```
int
texture_gl_create(texture_t* texture)
{
    int err;

    if (texture->id) {
        err = texture_gl_delete(texture);
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    GL_CHECK(glGenTextures, 1, &texture->id);
    LOGD("Texture has id: %d", texture->id);

    GL_CHECK(glBindTexture, texture->target, texture->id);

    switch (texture->byte) {
        case 1:
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
            break;
    }

    GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri, texture->target,
             GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri, texture->target,
             GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri, texture->target,
             GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri, texture->target,
             GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GL_CHECK(glTexImage2D, texture->target, 0,
             texture->iformat,
             texture->width, texture->height, 0,
             texture->format, texture->type,
             texture->pixels);

    GL_CHECK(glBindTexture, texture->target, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

[A simple look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q185O.png) at the memory allocation shows that the call to glTextImage2D loads 8MB into memory !

From our understanding this is because the call to `glTexImage2D` loads a RAW file from the texture-target data into memory. Therefore there's roughly 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA) x 1920 x 1080 = 8.1 MB.

I can hardly believe that this is how the video game industry handles the problem, there must be a much better way to load images into memory.

My question is therefore, what's the best way to load images in OpenGL (ES) so that we use as little memory as possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [texture compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_compression). These special compression algorithms like [PVRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVRTC) allow fast on-the-fly decompression in the image pipeline, reducing video memory consumption and texture upload times.

When using [glCompressedTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCompressedTexImage2D.xml) you need to specify the type of compression (internal format) used, and you will need to figure out which compression is supported by the GPU [by checking the extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148795/android-opengl-texture-compression).

Comment: indeed this what I ended looking into, thanks @Aert. Also, I've found [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW1) for iOS which explains how Apple deals with the problem.