# How to stop Unity from post processing my JPG's?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to turn off all post processing of images?  The reason, my images are normally only 200 MB.  But after Unity spins them they are 1.2 GB.  Plus I like my originals - they are sRGB and usually Unity strips the sRGB from the images..

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be two answers to possibly fix this issue that my programmer dug up for me.  I will let you know if it works!!!

Although these answers are mostly about the memory issue they do touch down on the file issue as well.

[Unity increases size of imported sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210866/unity-increases-size-of-imported-sprites)

https://answers.unity.com/questions/605062/why-do-image-file-size-becomes-huge-on-import.html