# Export an 8Bit AlphaFormat for ThreeJs

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a simple three.js application. I'm trying to texture some geometry. My hardware is VERY memory constrained. Conveniently, my texture is grayscale. So I figured I could try and save the texture in an 8-bit format and then load it using AlphaFormat as the texture's pixel format? I was hoping this could help keep my video memory usage down. Does anyone have experience with doing something like that? Its just wasteful for my application to load 3 channels worth of color for a grayscale image. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: If there are memory constraints you need to try the compress texture format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148795/android-opengl-texture-compression
There are couple of sample on compress texture with three js also you can check. Plus also check on hardware you going to deploy support the http://alteredqualia.com/tmp/webgl-maxparams-test/ 
check for supported extension for texture compression

Comment: What's your question?